Reboot Windows Server after User Data script execution with AWS CDK
I am using AWS CDK to set up Windows servers. The initial setup is done running a PowerShell script which joins the EC2 instance with our AD. This step requires a reboot.
How can it be achieved?
I am using Windows 2022 and AWS CDK V2.
I found that exiting the PowerShell script with
exit 3010

should do the job, see
see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch-v2-settings.html#ec2launch-v2-exit-codes-reboots
Unfortunately it does not.

Do you have ssm configured for the instance as it use ssm to do the reboot. You can also get instance id from the script and then use aws cli command to reboot it. You instance profile/role must have permission to reboot the instance.

could you create an EventBridge event from your UserData and restart the instance based on that event (e.g. from a Lambda)
